# An extra blank line before the program terminates

Tags: c

I'm really new to programming and just wanted to ask a quick question.
So I made this program that reads off whatever the user inputs, then output the exact same thing until the user presses enter without any input.

```
int main(void) {
    char s1[30];

    while (s1[0] != NULL) {
        gets(s1);
        printf("%s\n", s1);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I realized that when I press enter to end the program, the program creates an extra blank line before the program terminates.

So I changed my code as it is below

```
int main(void) {
    char s1[30];

    while (1) {
        gets(s1);
        if (s1[0] == NULL)
            break;
        printf("%s\n", s1);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And now the program terminates without creating an extra blank line. But I really can't seem to figure out the factors that made the difference between two codes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `gets`. Never *ever* use `gets`! It's a [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function that have even been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: `gets` is not valid C. `s1[0] == NULL` is not valid C. Burn your book/teacher with fire and get a new one.

Comment: Also note that `NULL` is for null *pointers*, not the string null terminator (which is `'\0'`). And uninitialized local variables (including arrays like `s1`) will really be uninitialized, and have *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already told in the comment section don't use `gets` it is dangerous([why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)).

And replace `gets` with `fgets` as below.

```
while (fgets(s1,sizeof s1,stdin)) {
    if (s1[0] == '\n') //fgets() reads the newline into the buffer
     break;
     printf("%s", s1); // Don't need to append \n to print as s1 will be having \n already.
}
```

---

To answer your question

```
gets(s1);
if (s1[0] == NULL) // Not valid comparison use \0 instead of NULL
```

When you press `enter` to terminate the program, `gets` will not read the newline(`\n`) character into the buffer hence your `s1` will be untouched by `gets` and will have indeterminate values(seemingly it is having `0's` in your case) so you are hitting `if (s1[0] == NULL)` and  breaking out of the loop without printing newline.